# Why does declaration order matter for generic members?

Tags: f#

Today I noticed that the following does not compile:

```ml
open System

type MyType() =        
    member this.Something() =
        this.F(3)
        this.F("boo") 
        //     ^^^^^
        // This expression was expected to have type 'int' but here has type 'string'
        
    member private this.F<'T> (t:'T) =
        //                ^^
        // This type parameter has been used in a way that constrains it to always be 'int'
        // This code is less generic than required by its annotations because the explicit type variable 'T' could not be generalized. It was constrained to be 'int'.
        Console.WriteLine (t.GetType())
```

But simply change the declaration order, and there's no problem.

```ml
open System

type MyType() =        
    member private this.F<'T> (t:'T) =
        Console.WriteLine (t.GetType())
        
    member this.Something() =
        this.F(3)
        this.F("boo")
```

This took me a long while to figure out as I didn't expect declaration order to matter for members of a class. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a subtle side-effect of how the F# type inference works. I do not think there is a better workaround for the issue than reordering your definitions.

To provide more background, the members of a class are automatically treated as mutually recursive (meaning that they can call each other). Unlike with multiple types or multiple functions in a module, you do not need to declare this explicitly using the `rec` keyword.

However, the issue is not limited to classes. You can get exactly the same behaviour with simple functions. The simplest possible example is:

```
let rec test() = 
  f 3       // Warning: causes code to be less generic
  f "boo"   // Error: string does not match int
and f (arg:'a) = ()
```

In the opposite order, this works just fine:

```
let rec f (arg:'a) = ()
and test() = 
  f 3
  f "boo"
```

The issue is that the type-checker analyzes the code from top to bottom. In the first case, it:

- Sees `f 3` and infers that `f` is of type `int -> unit`
- Sees `f "boo"` and reports a type error
- Sees `f (arg:'a)` and realizes it prematurely used a more specific type than needed (and reports the various warnings).

In the second case, it:

- Sees `f (arg:'a)` and infers that `f` is of type `'a -> unit`
- Sees `f 3` and `f "boo"` and uses appropriate type instantiation

The main reason for why the type checker cannot be more clever is that the type checker only does "generalization" (i.e. figures out that a function is generic) *after* it analyzes the whole body of the function (or the whole recursive block). If it encounters a more specific use inside the body, it never gets to this generalization step.

Comment: I see. Well, at least it's consistent and not limited to classes. I suppose this wouldn't be considered a bug, although it definitely was surprising to me.

Comment: I think the key point is "the members of a class are automatically treated as mutually recursive". This is a "subtle side-effect". IMO, this is a point where something should be done to improve. Why I find it acceptable with rec functions, I think it is less acceptable with class methods. I would prefer if methods are not implicitly recursive. Requiring to explicitly put a "rec" when a method needs to be recursive would be a better compromise. Mutually recursive could be done using the "and" keyword as happens with other constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Just like file order matters in F#, line order matters too. In general, nothing that is declared later in a file is available to expressions earlier in that file.
It takes a while to get used to but ultimately is a great way to prevent you from accidentally writing spaghetti code.
There are some exceptions:

- [Recursive Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/modules#recursive-modules)
- [Mutually Recursive Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/recursive-functions-the-rec-keyword#mutually-recursive-functions)
- [Mutually Recursive Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/classes#mutually-recursive-types)

but I don't think there's any mechanism to allow putting a generic declaration later in file and probably just something you need to know about how F# works.

Comment: It just seems weird that this would work for non-generic members but cause a type constraint issue for generic ones. I'm looking for a sound reason for that behavior; if I can't find one I'll open an issue on Github.

Comment: Because the type is inferred based on the first use unless it is explicitly declared to be generic.